# Two ListViews in one activity in android 3.0 and above

Tags: android, android-listview

In Android `2.1` and `2.3` it works fine. But for `3.0` and above `findViewById` does not find the second `ListView`. I have already tried cleaning the project, tried not using `ListActivity` too, nothing helped. Any ideas?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(List1Adaptor);
    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView2);
    list2.setAdapter(List2Adapter);//Null Pointer
}
```

the main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/ListView2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
 </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/listLayout_relativeLayout2"
android:layout_height="320dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" >

<ListView            
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you instanciate you adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml file is missing a root view. I'm surprised it works on any version of Android. You should surround everything with a linear layout or something like that.

Comment: I didnt post it. It was too big. But this is actually something i didnt try at all, to reorder the main.xml. I have many Linear & Relative Layouts crossover. thanks

Comment: i solve it. well, i guess that some of the Layouts was the problem. Just had to remove the useless ones.
thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your layout has `android:id="@+id/listView2"` (note: lowercase 'l') and your Java code is requesting `R.id.ListView2` (note: uppercase 'L'). Try using the same case in both situations.

Comment: ou sorry about that, it was a mistake while trying to simplify the code. i did changed it.